# Struggling With LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to store date inputted into a html input field, this data will then change the current speed limit for the user, if it exceeds a certain number then it will alert the user that they are speeding. I think the code is right but I suppose there is some sort of logic error that I am not seeing here. Hope someone can help as right now it does not seem to work or spew an error message for me to fix.

HTML

```
 s <input type="text" id="limit1">
```

JS

```
 var limitfield = document.getElementById('limit1') //places bgcolor1 field from HTML into variable 
 limitfield.addEventListener('input', updateStorage); //Adds eventlistener to listen to input in bgcolour field then call method

 function updateStorage (){
 localStorage.setItem('limitfield', checkSpeed.value); //After obtaining the input from eventlistener store bgcolor.value
 setPreference();
 }

function setPreference(){
 var myPreference = localStorage.getItem('limitfield'); //variable that retrieves value from bgcolor 
     checkSpeed.value = myPreference; //style background colour by calling variable
 }


function checkSpeed(limit){
    if (speed > limit) {
      alert("speeding");
   }
    } checkSpeed(20);
```

Comment: So, what exactly isn't working? What are you expecting and what's happening?

Comment: @Jeremy Thille When the application is started I would like it to store a default limit of 20, when the user inputs something in the input field, it should be stored locally and replace the limit to what they have placed.

Comment: you are assigning `checkSpeed.value` but `checkSpeed` is a function. No idea what this is supposed to do. Provide a  proper explanation of what this code should do...broken code is not a good substitute for an explantion

Comment: @charlietfl yes, I figured that was an issue, do you think it should be limit.value? I want it to replace the limit

Comment: You're not reading the value of the input field anywhere...  I'm struggling to understand what this little piece of code is supposed to do

Comment: @JeremyThille I have placed an event listener to listen to input, is that a problem?

Comment: You're catching the input event, but that doesn't mean you're reading the value. Where are you reading the input's value?

Comment: @JeremyThille well, I would like the input value stored to change the limit of the function, I had hoped that checkSpeed.value = myPreference; reads the input and changes the limit to say 30 instead of the default 20

Comment: `checkSpeed` is the function that checks the speed. `checkSpeed.value` is undefined, this doesn't make sense. You mean `limitfield.value`, don't you?

Comment: @JeremyThille If I changed it to limitfield.value would it change the limit in the function? Right now it is set to 20 using  `checkSpeed(20);`

Comment: Stop making wild guesses. Right now you're randomly using an undefined value of something else and hope it'll somehow change a limit somewhere. `limitfield` is an input. This is what you want to check the value of. Read the input field's value and use it.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, I want to read the input of `limitfield` but I want to change the value of `limit` to the value inputted into `limitfield`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of your issues. You never give it speed only the limit so speed is undefined. Speed can never be greater than undefined so it never fires. Pass in speed to the function and it should give you the result you want.

```
function checkSpeed(limit){
    if (speed > limit) {
      alert("speeding");
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not the only issue. `checkSpeed.value` is also undefined. The code still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, sorry guys I should have disclosed this in the beginning.

Speed is a variable created in the beginning that works out the speed of the user, by diving distance over time. I should have added it in the code but chose not too because it was too long and I assumed that it was not necessary, I know I am at fault for not disclosing it beforehand

Comment: You should add a more minimal working example of your code. Right now none of it works and there are a lot of unknowns.